# Invalid argument error while using umount() function

Tags: c++, system, mount, umount

I am trying to unmount a usb-storage device through a c++ code as follows.

```
  while(umount("/dev/sdc1/")!=0)
  {
    std::cout << "ERROR: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(2));
  }
```

But, I get an error saying: Invalid argument.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is that error when you compile or is that what `errno` is saying when you execute? If the latter, what happens when you open a terminal and run `ls /dev/sdc1`?

Comment: This is the error I get when I execute.

Comment: @scohe001 when I run ls /dev/sdc1, output is: "/dev/sdc1"

Comment: When you run your executable, are you doing it as root (ie: `sudo ./a.out`)?

Comment: @scohe001 yes I am running it as a root